# convert irregular time series to hourly data in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
                read            value
0     2013-01-07 05:00:00        29.0
1     2013-01-08 15:00:00      4034.0
2     2013-01-09 20:00:00    256340.0
3     2013-01-10 20:00:00    343443.0
4     2013-01-11 20:00:00    4642435.0
5     2013-01-12 15:00:00    544296.0
6     2013-01-13 20:00:00    700000.0
7     2013-01-14 20:00:00    782335.0
8     2013-01-15 19:00:00    900000.0
9     2013-01-16 20:00:00    959130.0
10    2013-01-17 19:00:00   1114343.0
11    2013-01-18 20:00:00   1146230.0
12    2013-01-19 20:00:00   1247793.0
13    2013-01-20 20:00:00   1343376.0
```

I would like to convert it and normalize so that it shows the hourly consumption over time. So far I have the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#caluclates hourly delta
current['hour_delta'] = (current['read'] - current['read'].shift()).fillna(0).astype('timedelta64[h]')


#adds end date and then amount per hours
current['end_date'] = current['read'] + pd.to_timedelta(current['hour_delta'], unit='h')
current['infer_hour'] = current['value'] / current['hour_delta']
```

I then create the series

```
#create hourly time series
result = pd.Series(0, index=pd.date_range(start=current['read'].min(), end=current['read'].max(), freq='h'))
```

However from here I have not been able to figure out how to apply the hourly rate to the series.

Comment: You need `pandas.DatetimeIndex().resample()`, it does exactly what you want. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: How would I apply it in this case? I have a feeling I am making this too complicated

Comment: I provided a link to the documentation. It has examples.

Comment: @DYZ, if I understand OP correctly - it's not that straightforward, because of upsampling...

Comment: @MaxU What's wrong with up-resampling?

Comment: if I use resample to I still need the result series? Also I believe @MaxU is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resample hourly on the `read` column.  Then interpolate to fill the null values.  Then take the differences of each row with the next.

For example, there are 34 hours between `2013-01-07 05:00:00` and `2013-01-08 15:00:00`.  If I have to distribute `4034` over 34 hours then each hour should be an average of `4034 / 34` or `118.647059`

```
current.set_index('read').value.cumsum().resample('H').sum().interpolate().diff()

read
2013-01-07 05:00:00             NaN
2013-01-07 06:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 07:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 08:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 09:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 10:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 11:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 12:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 13:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 14:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 15:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 16:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 17:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 18:00:00      118.647059
2013-01-07 19:00:00      118.647059
...
```

Comment: I want to show the average hourly rate for all hours. that is why I create the result series

Comment: looks correct to me. I seem to be getting this error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: This is smart !

Comment: I tried to set the index before the resample with no luck. I assume this is because there are duplicates in my read column?

Comment: @user3609179 I'm testing it out... Yes, that is correct.  I produced a duplicate and got the error... give me a moment.  Ok!!  I added a `sum` after the `resample` to consolidate any duplicates.

Comment: Ok It looks great. One more thing looking at the values overtime they seem to be summing? I would like the average over each interval if I remove cumsum() will that handle it?

Comment: The `cumsum` is like the inverse of `diff`.  The only issue I can think of is if the duplicates are in fact duplicates.  You can try to replace the `sum` with `mean`.  Otherwise, you should provide enough data that demonstrates the problem and we'll figure it out right away.

Comment: @user3609179 I'm glad that worked.  However, I have to warn you.  That having worked indicates to me that your data is messed up.  The `mean` is a device that aggregates values over an hour and should only apply when there are multiple values per hour.  I imagined having two records an half hour apart.  Should we sum the values up over those two records?  I thought so.  But instead, we are taking the mean.  That implies that both records are valid representations for the entire hour and instead of choosing one, we took the average.  All I'm saying is "dbl check the data"

Comment: Yes I think something is wrong as I am no experiencing negative values

Comment: I think what is causing this is I have unique IDs associated with multiple of these time series.

Comment: Ahh, ask a new question with this new element.

Comment: I think the problem that in some cases the numbers slightly decrease. Also it seems the numbers still seem to be continually adding up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149632/discussion-between-user3609179-and-pirsquared).